# How to fetch max 5 set of data from JSON array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to fetch any 5 set of data randomly from JSON array using PHP. I am explaining my code below.

```
$result = array(
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'2',
        'cat_name'=>'spirit',
        'subcat_id'=>'20',
        'subcat_name'=>'pizza'
        ),
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'3',
        'cat_name'=>'Food',
        'subcat_id'=>'23',
        'subcat_name'=>'pakhal'
        ),
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'2',
        'cat_name'=>'spirit',
        'subcat_id'=>'22',
        'subcat_name'=>'wine'
        ),
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'2',
        'cat_name'=>'spirit',
        'subcat_id'=>'20',
        'subcat_name'=>'pizza'
        ),
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'3',
        'cat_name'=>'Food',
        'subcat_id'=>'24',
        'subcat_name'=>'fuddy'
        ),
    array(
        'cat_id'=>'4',
        'cat_name'=>'Continetal',
        'subcat_id'=>'25',
        'subcat_name'=>'cont'
        )
    );

echo json_encode($result);
```

Here I need to fetch max 5 nos of data randomly from the above array.

Comment: if this data from some SQL, then at that code add `LIMIT 5`

Comment: No not exactly from SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Select 5 random keys from $result by array_rand and get them

```
json_encode(
  array_values(
   array_intersect_key($result,
       array_flip(array_rand($result, 5)))));
```

Comment: The result came like this `{"0":{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"spirit","subcat_id":"20","subcat_name":"pizza"},"1":{"cat_id":"3","cat_name":"Food","subcat_id":"23","subcat_name":"pakhal"},"2":{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"spirit","subcat_id":"22","subcat_name":"wine"},"3":{"cat_id":"2","cat_name":"spirit","subcat_id":"20","subcat_name":"pizza"},"5":{"cat_id":"4","cat_name":"Continetal","subcat_id":"25","subcat_name":"cont"}}`. not proper array format.

Comment: Reset index by array_values. I've updates the answer

Comment: Its fine now. Thank you.